# Oracle Stored procedure - execute for all the select result

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g

Say I have a stored procedure which accepts 2 varchars, does some processing and updates my business tables. Is there a way that I can run the stored procedure for the results from a select query?

Like,

```
execute my_stored_proc select varchar_1,varchar_2 from an_ip_table;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over results by loop

```
BEGIN
   FOR RECS IN (SELECT varchar_1, varchar_2 FROM an_ip_table)
   LOOP
      my_stored_proc (RECS.varchar_1, RECS.varchar_2);
   END LOOP;
END
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be a simple way:

```
begin
    for i in (
                select varchar_1, varchar_2
                from an_ip_table
              )
    loop
        my_stored_proc(i.varchar_1, i.varchar_2);
    end loop;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Initially, I thought of just to put a comment, but this needs some explanation, so I'm writing an answer. You are actually doing it the wrong way. Ideally, you should be passing a **cursor** to your `my_stored_proc` and fetching the cursor inside the procedure. Your method actually causes *multiple calls* to procedure for every row from the query result. The processing will be very slow if you have huge volume of data. It is a bad idea even if there are few rows.

Here is a sample procedure that does a dml operation using `FORALL`.It is just a sample, but you should be able to convert your select query such that you should be able to do dml this way.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_stored_proc (
    p_iptab_cur SYS_REFCURSOR
) AS

    TYPE iprec IS RECORD ( col1   an_ip_table.col1%TYPE,
    col2   an_ip_table.col1%TYPE );
    TYPE iptype IS
        TABLE OF iprec;
    ips    iptype;
BEGIN
    FETCH p_iptab_cur BULK COLLECT INTO ips;

    FORALL i IN ips.FIRST..ips.LAST 
    --Your DML--  using the collection of records.
END;
/


--Calling the procedure by passing the `CURSOR`

DECLARE
  x SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
   OPEN x FOR select col1, col2
                from an_ip_table;
   my_stored_proc(x);
END;
/
```